# How to get text to show outside of the previous div area?

Tags: css, html

With the code below $title1 and $title2 should be outside of the div and centered against the width of the page.  It only does this because I have the "Y" there.  If I remove the "Y" the text moves up and it's centered the address class.  Obviously I can't keep the "Y" there but not sure why that changes things.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body { margin:12pt auto 12pt auto;width:568pt; }
            .sseal { float:left; width:56.25pt; }
            .address { float:left;text-align:center; margin:15px auto;width:450pt; }
            .dseal { float:right; width:56.25pt;}
            wrapper { margin:0px auto; }
            .form_title { text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-size:22pt; }
            .header { font-weight:bold; }
            .heading { font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold; }
            .title1 { font-size:24pt;font-weight:bold;text-align:center; }
            .title2 { font-size:22pt;font-weight:bold; font-style:oblique;text-align:center; }
            table, th, td { padding:10px; }
            hr { padding:0px;spacing:0px;margin:0px; }
            .rightpaced { margin:45px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">   
            <div class="sseal"><img src="../image2.gif" height="75" width="75" border="0"></div>
            <div class="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="address">
                <font size=+1><b>
                $companyname<br>
                $address
                </b></font>
            </div>
            <div class="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="dseal"><img src="../image2.gif" height="75" width="75" border="0"></div>
            <div class="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear:both;"></div>
        Y<br>
        <div class="title1">$title1</div>
        <p>
        <div class="title2">$title2</div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's better not to post such a lengthy code, but only some very-relevant parts, and the rest in a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) containing all the code.

Comment: You should make a fiddle showing the problem. There's lots of problems besides this title thing in your code btw. For one, none of your img tags end correctly. Make the last bracket of the img tags be like this `/>`

Comment: Also, this is *very* old HTML. Unless there is some limitation, you should use current day styling. For example, `<br />` tags are no longer necessary(though you can use `float` and `clear` CSS styles), and `<img />` tags' styling (width, height) should be done via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless you have some limitation (browser-support, this is an assignment that has to be done this way), I'd suggest you use newer (CSS2 and CSS3) selectors and HTML tags (for instance, the `<br />` is not used much anymore).

See [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) for more information on newer HTML and CSS. The site has  excellent examples and tutorials as well.

**EDIT:** See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSlaver/PkwEv/) of the layout you wanted (I think).

Comment: Thanks.  I did use W3Schools for most if not all of this.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp  It doesn't mention it was depreciated although I did see it say some other things I was looking at was depreciated.   I will use jsFiddle next time.  Thanks.

Comment: The `<br />` tag is not *exactly* deprecated, though it is supported. It's just rarely used anymore. Check out [this section](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for better web-design.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QFjwF/  I've added the header and removed the "Y" and it didn't work.  When I added the "Y" back it worked.  Maybe I wasn't clear about the problem.  The problem isn't that it isn't centering because it is, the problem is that it's centering between the images and it shouldn't.

Comment: Can you make a simple drawing (in paint) how you would like the layout to be?

Comment: I could give a screenshot but where would I upload it?  It's the jsFiddle link.  I want it to look like that but without showing the "Y".  If you notice, with the "Y" Mainframe Support & Data Storage and Recovery is the width of the page.  Without the "Y" it is restricted to the previous div.  Not sure what I would use in place of <br />. It's almost the shortest code to use.  I've changed the img attributes as suggested as well.